# Parallel lines inside of polygon

Tags: qgis, line, parallel

I have an irregular polygon.

I want to make parallel lines with 14 meters of space between the inside of the polygon using QGIS, does not matter the direction, but it is necessary to have the least lines as possible.

Comment: Find the longest axis of the polygon, then add lines parallel to that.

Comment: I've tried the sugestion of GBG, bur it does not necessary make the least number of lines.
I am not sure if in an irregular polygon, if I take the longest one and then add parallels, I will get the least number of lines

Answer (score 1):

Zoom to your polygons extent.  Use *Processing - QGIS geoalgorithm - Vector Creation Tool - Create Grid* to make a line grid at the same processing extent at the current window at your spacing preference.  Manual delete the horizontal or vertical lines and save your edits.  Use Use *Processing - QGIS geoalgorithm - Vector Overlay Tools - Clip* to clip the parallel lines to your polygon.

Comment: I've tried this, bur it does not work, because the software make the grid as squares up north, not necessary in the best way, with least squares. I am planing to use it as crop row project